# Getting Django user details into my django db.sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, django-forms, user-input

How can I get user information such as sign-up and login details into django database 'db.sqliet3' ?

I was creating a sign-up page of a website using django and my expectations was to get the details entered by the user saved into django database 'db.sqlite' once they sign-up and whenever they want to login they just login using the details such as password they used when signing up to the website.